# Wait for index to flush with Hibernate Search and JUnit

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm writing a JUnit test for a Hibernate Search (Lucene) repo.  In a `@Before` method, I persist an entity, and then in a `@Test` method, I want to search for it.  Problem is, the index is apparently not updated by the time the test method is run.

My test class is annotated with `@Transactional`.  I tried annotating just the `@Before` method with `@Transactional`, but I must be doing something wrong because Hibernate Search complains about a lack of session while indexing (trying to access lazy loaded properties).

I even tried `sleep()`ing at the beginning of the test method, to no avail.

I tried calling `Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager).createIndexer().startAndWait()` in the `@Before` method, but that appears to run forever.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to annotate the test as Transactional as you might need to control the transaction.
Hibernate Search is going to flush the changes to the index at transaction commit: you need to commit the transaction before running the query.

As an alternative *FullTextSession* has a method *flushToIndexes()* which you could use to force an immediate flush, but then you're not testing the full end to end transactional behavior. Also if you flush the changes to the index, a transaction rollback won't undo them so if you're attempting to have transactional tests to keep them independent that's not going to be good enough.

Comment: This was one of the things I tried, but I kept running into the `Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead` issue.  I was injecting the `EntityManager` using the `@PersistenceContext` annotation, then calling `getTransaction().begin()` and `...commit()`.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't use Spring so I can't tell you what exactly is wrong with the configuration, but I'm pretty sure your transactions are not configured correctly. BTW that's an error from Spring, not from Hibernate as for Hibernate it's perfectly valid.